# How to read and write to same Excel sheet (HSSF/XSSF) simultaneously using multi-threading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-poi, coding-efficiency

I have requirement to read an Excel sheet and write to the same sheet in Java. It works well with single thread. Since it processes record by record it becomes time consuming process. I want to process multiple records at a time using multithreading.

Sample file - File.xlsx

[image]

Name & Age are read from the sheet and applied some logic and written to remarks column.

Let's say I have 1000 records, I want to divide 500 records to process simultaneously using multithreading.

In the above scenario 2 threads start reading (Name & Age column) and writing (Remarks column) to the same Excel sheet.

1st thread should process 1 to 500,
2nd thread should process 501 to 1000

How can I get the optimal solution on this? I'm using POI jar to process the Excel.

Comment: [Can I access/modify workbooks/documents/slideshows in multiple threads? What are the multi-threading guarantees that Apache POI makes](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10224)

Comment: Where is the code you have done with single thread? Where is your attempt. Frankly speaking, it is unclear on what you trying to do for a very specific question.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is unlikely to work reliably.  It comes down to the thread-safety properties of Apache POI.   The [FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html) says this:

> *"In short: Handling different document-objects in different threads will work. Accessing the same document in multiple threads will not work."*

You want to use multiple threads to read and write the same spreadsheet at the same time.  That is the use-case that the FAQ says is unsafe.

---

> How can I get the optimal solution on this?

For a faster solution you will need to use some other representation for your data (i.e. not an Excel spreadsheet) while processing it:

- You could get Excel to export the data as a CSV file, process the file to create a new CSV, then re-import the CSV into the spreadsheet.
- You could move away from spreadsheets entirely; e.g. use a database.

Alternatively, if you were coding in C#, you would have the option of interacting directly with the Excel application.  See the following Q&A for some ideas.

- [Write to excel file with multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344273/write-to-excel-file-with-multiple-threads)